# readonly attribute doesn't work for input type="date" in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

You can edit the html below by focusing on the box and pressing the space key.

```html
<input type="date" readonly>
```

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Can you use `disabled` instead of `readonly`?

Comment: Yes, [`tabindex="-1"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: and where is the js code?

Comment: @ChrisG no JavaScript needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @SalmanA yes but it has the js tag in the question and he doesn't explain if he expects a js solution or something

Comment: @chris I can remove the tags if they're upsetting you. The solution could use JavaScript.

Comment: Seems to be fixed for Firefox 123.0 (64-bit) - Focussing the date input and pressing space doesn't show the date picker anymore(, which it did before updating FF)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `disabled` as `readonly` isn't fully supported in browsers and so there are holes in the implementation such as the one you've highlighted here

Comment: FWIW: Using `disabled` inputs in a form will prevent their values from being posted to a server's backend, if applicable

Comment: Better advice would be to use type=text, readonly. After all, a readonly datepicker is same as readonly text box... both do nothing except possibly hold a value to post with the associated form.